# Initialization of typedef struct with new

Tags: c++, pointers, struct, new-operator, glfw

I'm using GLFW and creating a GLFWwindow, which is declared in it's header "glfw3.h" like this:

`typedef struct GLFWwindow GLFWwindow;`

Generally, when initializing a struct on the heap I do something like this:

```
GLFWwindow *window = new GLFWwindow();
```

This gives me the following error: 
invalid use of incomplete type ‘GLFWwindow {aka struct GLFWwindow}’,
forward declaration of ‘GLFWwindow {aka struct GLFWwindow}’

Here is my fix for that problem:

`GLFWwindow **window = new GLFWwindow*();`

This fix actually works, but I don't understand why I need it.

1. I don't understand why the struct GLFWwindow is not complete or why I do a forward declaration. Seems like something is not declared correctly. What exactly have I done wrong?
2. What is operator new doing, when given a pointer to a type?

Thx in advance

Comment: You've only declared the class, and `new GLFWindow()` requires its definition. When you create a pointer of that type it only needs the declaration.

Comment: You're simply missing an appropriate include containing the declaration of `GLFWwindow`. I don't believe your _"fix actually works"_, besides getting rid of the compiler errors.

Comment: *`GLFWwindow **window = new GLFWwindow*();`* this is not doing what you think it does.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: He's not missing an include, user code should not be creating a `GLFWwindow`, they should be using [`glfwCreateWindow`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344)

Comment: @MooingDuck Yes, I realized this a few minutes ago. (good I didn't give an answer in that direction ;P )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As it was said by others, you can't directly create `GLFWindow` with `new`, because it's only declared, not defined.

In fact, it serves as [opaque type](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga3c96d80d363e67d13a41b5d1821f3242), and you are supposed to use only GLFW functions to manipulate it. For example you can create a window using [glfwCreateWindow() function](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344), that is:

```
GLFWwindow* window = glfwCreateWindow(...);
```

Comment: Right! Thanks for your answer, I didn't know about opaque data types, but this seems to be the correct answer!
The reason why I used new here is because I have a manager class, which should contain a pointer to the window. In It's constructor I just wanted to allocate memory and then later in an init function I call glfwCreateWindow(). 
Do you have any suggestion how to do this correctly? I don't like my "solution"

Comment: @user3453494 You don't need to allocate the memory yourself, just create a variable/class member of type `GLFWindow*` and assign to it as I have shown.

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works, thanks a lot. It really can be that easy... afterwards ;-)

So for completeness and summarising: my awful fix worked, because I first allocated memory for the pointer to my object (which is nonsense). Then, later in the code, I allocated the memory to the object itself by using glfwCreateWindow().

The reason why new itself didn't work on the window object is that it is an opaque data type.

Answer (score 3):

You need a *definition* of the struct to be able to instantiate it. But you seem to have only a *declaration* (missing `#include`?).

I believe your 'fix' compiles, but it doesn't actually *work*: it allocates a new pointer to a struct, but it does not create a struct to be pointed to.

Comment: The OP mentions the header file containing the `GLFWwindow` declaration. Though if doing so with a forward declaration and inlined code the `new GLFWwindow()` it still won't work.

Comment: He's not missing an include, user code should not be creating a `GLFWwindow`, they should be using [`glfwCreateWindow`](http://www.glfw.org/docs/latest/group__window.html#ga5c336fddf2cbb5b92f65f10fb6043344)

Comment: I do have the header included. GLFWwindow *window = NULL does also compile well, but I'm not sure if that actually verifies that I included correctly.

My "fix" does not only compile, it really does work correctly. Later, I initialize it like this: *window = glfwCreateWindow(somesize, somesize, "somestring", NULL, NULL);

Now, I am aware that this "fix" looks awkward and awfully wrong! I don't want to use it in this way, that's why I ask the question

Comment: @user3453494 If you already know about `glfwCreateWindow()` why are you so insistent on dynamically allocating the pointer?